# Floating point inconsistency in mono

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine, mono, monodevelop

I trid this in .NET immediate window:

```
30f + 0.5f
```

And get 30.5 as expected. In mono, I get 30 instead. What is the reason?

Details:

- .NET: Visual Studio 2010 SP1
- mono: Unity3D 3.5.6f4 equipped with MonoDevelop 2.8.2

Comment: +1 And 29f + 1.5f is **31** ;-)

Comment: Can you post some code to show this? Mono in Unity works fine for me with those kind of additions. Are you storing the result as an Integer maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your MonoDevelop to 3.0.5

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck with the version that comes with Unity3D. Maybe next version of Unity3D comes with an updated version of Mono, but in the meanwhile I need to use a workaround to this bug...

Comment: There's no workarounds... what happens is that the evaluator casts all primitive types (except string) to a long to add/subtract/multiply/divide/etc and then casts back into the actual type. Obviously, the person who wrote the original code overlooked doubles and floats, so I added support for those in 3.0